# How to make webpack watch simple script

Tags: webpack, watch

I have a website where I am introducing some react.

I have a script in my `package.json` that has just:

```
"dev": "webpack --watch"
```

It does not work though. Each time I update scripts it should refresh the output files, but it's not.

What am I missing?

This is my `webpack`:

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const postcssPresetEnv = require("postcss-preset-env");

const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
module.exports = {
    mode: devMode ? "development" : "production",
    entry: {
        "style.main": [
            "./Content/css/bootstrap.min.css",
            "./Content/sass/public/style.scss"
        ],
        "app": [
            "./app/src/app.js"
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "content/dist"),
        publicPath: "/css",
        filename: "js/[name].js"
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(c|sa|sc)ss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            importLoaders: 2
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            ident: "postcss",
                            plugins: devMode
                                ? () => []
                                : () => [
                                    postcssPresetEnv({
                                        browsers: [">1%"]
                                    }),
                                    require("cssnano")()
                                ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: "[name].[ext]",
                            publicPath: "../images",
                            emitFile: false
                        } 
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: devMode ? "css/[name].css" : "css/[name].min.css"
        })
    ]
};
```

app.js has just this:

```
console.log('Webpack watch is not working again');
```

I imagine it should refresh the message in the console each time I amend it in `app.js`?

I'm using webpack 4.41.6 and webpack-cli 3.3.11

**EDIT**

I have actually dev script (which calls webpack --watch) running in VS task runner and I can see it's compiling the source each time on save but the dist is not really refreshing in the browser.

This is the only issue.

Answer (score 0):

you have to [update the browser manually](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-watch-mode) using webpack `watch mode`.
if you want auto refresh and [HMR](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/), read howto setup [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-server).

Comment: I am not sure this is the right way to go. The links you posted are for a SPA, mine is not. When I set up web server it just opens at default port and lists all folders and files of the indicated directory, it's not running the website. The website is running on another port. I was working on a app like mine before and we weren't using web server, watch was working though

Comment: I have actually dev script running in VS task runner and I can see it's compiling the source each time on save but the dist is not really refreshing in the browser. I have updated my question with this info @tfr

Comment: please read the docs properly, doesn't matter if spa or static html. again:
"The only downside is that you have to refresh your browser in order to see the changes. It would be much nicer if that would happen automatically as well, so let's try webpack-dev-server which will do exactly that." (https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-watch-mode)
mark answer as correct. thank you